Conflicts on spin directions in the molecular term symbol for O$_2$
We know that the ground-state electron configuration of O$_2$ is $K K (\sigma_g 2s)^2 (\sigma_u 2s)^2 (\sigma_g 2p_z)^2 (\pi_u 2p_x)^2 (\pi_u 2p_y)^2 (\pi_g 2p_x)^1 (\pi_g 2p_y)^1$. The spins of the electrons on the two outermost orbitals, $(\pi_g 2p_x)^1 (\pi_g 2p_y)^1$, are parallel. Because of this, the O$_2$ is paramagnetic.
However, according to molecular term symbol, the ground state of O$_2$ is $^3\Sigma$, which is a triplet state.
If we represent the combination of the $z$ component of orbital angular momentum, $m_l$, and $z$ component of spin angular momentum, $m_s$, as $m_l^{m_s}$, the $^3\Sigma$ has three states are (1$^+$, -1$^+$), (1$^-$, -1$^-$) and (1$^+$, -1$^-$).
The first two states have spins pointing to the same direction. 
But, in the last state, the spins are pointing to opposite directions.
How can the last state be paramagnetic?

I may made a misunderstanding on the origin of para-magnetism. It seems that as long as there are unpaired electrons, it can be para-magnetism. It is not necessary that they are parallel.
